# BSOD BCCode 124, request for analysis of my WinDGB log

Tags: windows-7, bsod, windbg, machine-check-exception

I've been experiencing system restarts for some time decribed with BSOD log by BCCode 124. I checked my RAM with MemTest for 3.5 hours with no error, then scaned system with Avast and Malwarebytes. Because problem was persisting I checked my log with Debugging Tools for Windows. Below you can find my WinDGB log. I'm not an expert and that's why I'm asking for your help for witch I'll be really grateful.

I see that something is wrong with my CPU, but is fixable or does it need to be replaced?

Cheers!

BTW. My CPU is C2D E4300 @ 2.44 GHz 1.35V, RAM: OCZ Platinium rev. 2 4-4-4-12 2.1V, MOBO Asus P5K

>

> Microsoft ® Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
>   Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\052314-21699-01.dmp]
>   Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available
>
> WARNING: Whitespace at end of path element
>   Symbol search path is: srv*c:\cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
>
> Executable search path is: 
>   Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
>   Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
>   Built by: 7601.18409.x86fre.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144
>   Machine Name:
>   Kernel base = 0x83447000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0x835905b0
>   Debug session time: Fri May 23 09:38:14.404 2014 (UTC + 2:00)
>   System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:12.043
>   Loading Kernel Symbols
>   .....................................................
>   Loading User Symbols
>   Mini Kernel Dump does not contain unloaded driver list
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.
>
> BugCheck 124, {0, 866e86f4, 0, 0}
>
> Probably caused by : hardware

### Followup: MachineOwner

> 0: kd> !analyze -v
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
>   A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
>   source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
>   WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
>   Arguments:
>   Arg1: 00000000, Machine Check Exception
>   Arg2: 866e86f4, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
>   Arg3: 00000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
>   Arg4: 00000000, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

### >Debugging Details:

> BUGCHECK_STR: 0x124_GenuineIntel
>
> CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT: 1
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT
>
> PROCESS_NAME: System
>
> CURRENT_IRQL: 0
>
> STACK_TEXT: 
>   8b513cc4 8351886d 866e86d8 835af988 835af980 nt!WheapCreateTriageDumpFromPreviousSession+0x32
>   8b513ce4 83519689 835af980 866e86d8 835af9b0 nt!WheapProcessWorkQueueItem+0x56
>   8b513d00 834c414b 835af980 00000000 856e0020 nt!WheapWorkQueueWorkerRoutine+0x1f
>   8b513d50 83650141 00000001 aee32367 00000000 nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x10d
>   8b513d90 834f7559 834c403e 00000001 00000000 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x9e
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 nt!KiThreadStartup+0x19
>
> STACK_COMMAND: kb
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME: MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: hardware
>
> IMAGE_NAME: hardware
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 0
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV
>
> BUCKET_ID: 0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV
>
> Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: I need the dmp file to see more details.

Comment: thanks for reply. Here you have the link to uploaded dmp file. <http://www.sendspace.com/file/nix5o7>

Comment: This might be heat related. Did you already cleaned the inside of the computer? If not, open the computer and use compressed air to remove all dust *(and go outside to do the cleaning)*.

Answer (score 3):

ok, I check the dump and you get a `BUSL0_SRC_ERR_M_NOTIMEOUT_ERR` error. That error (BUSL0_SRC_ERR_M_NOTIMEOUT_ERR) means the processor sent out a read request to L0 cache, and there was a delay in return (either a cache miss, or invalid data in cache).

This is mostly caused by overclocking the CPU.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: 866e86f4, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 00000000, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!WheapCreateTriageDumpFromPreviousSession
nt!WheapProcessWorkQueueItem
nt!WheapWorkQueueWorkerRoutine
nt!ExpWorkerThread
nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
nt!KiThreadStartup


BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x124_genuineintel_processor_bus_prv

---------

0: kd> !errrec 866e86f4

===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ 866e86f4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01cf7659ee291b44
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 5/23/2014 7:38:14 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000002 PreviousError

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 866e8774
Section       @ 866e884c
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x86
Error Type    : BUS error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 0
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000006f2
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000000

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 866e87bc
Section       @ 866e890c
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000000
CPU Id        : f2 06 00 00 00 08 02 00 - 9d e3 00 00 ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ 866e890c

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ 866e8804
Section       @ 866e898c
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : BUSL0_SRC_ERR_M_NOTIMEOUT_ERR (Proc 0 Bank 0)
  Status      : 0xf200084000000800


0: kd> !cpuid
CP  F/M/S  Manufacturer     MHz
 0  6,15,2  GenuineIntel    2437
```

The normal CPU speed for the E4300 is 1.8GHz. So revert the OC and run it it the designed CPU speed.

Comment: +1 but it would be nice to know for us mortals how you get from `866e86f4` to all the sections you show.

Comment: ok, I added the !errrec command.

Comment: <duh> don't rub it in :)